# Send a string from client to server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I wrote this:

Client:

```
printf("\nType a string: (STOP to ending connection)\n\n");
do{
    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && i < MAXLENGHT){
    buf[i++] = c;
}
buf[i] = '\0';
len = strlen(buf);
}
while( strcmp(buf,"STOP")!=0);
close(sockfd);
exit(0);
}
```

Server:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
int sock, fd;
socklen_t client_len;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;


if ((sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror ("Socket failed");
    exit (1);
}

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server.sin_port = htons (SERVER_PORT);


if (bind ( sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof server) == -1) {
    perror ("bind failed");
    exit (2);
}

listen (sock,1);


    while (1) {
    client_len = sizeof (client);
    if ((fd = accept ( sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len)) < 0) {
        perror ("accepting connection");
        exit(3);
    }
    fprintf (stderr, "\nOpen.\n");
    send (fd, "\nWelcome!\n", 50, 0);
    check_stats (fd, fd);}

    close(fd);
    fprintf (stderr, "\nClose\n");
    exit (0);


 }
```

.

```
void check_stats(int in, int out)
```

is a function where the server receives the string, do some things, and send it back to the client.
My question is:
In the server's code, what I have to put before

```
close(fd)
```

that when user types "STOP", server ends, but before ending, it sends another BYE string to the client? I'm having problems with the

```
recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

function. What I have to put, in my main, as

```
int sockfd
```

?

Comment: Just added a little detail to my question. If user type STOP, server send to client BYE and ends. Obviously, client read this message and then closes the connection

Comment: @WhozCraig, the awful indentation is misleading you. It's a `do {} while()` loop.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to read from TCP socket? Start here http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: @ugoren yes it is, sorry for my indentation, it's my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov I know how to read, my check_stats function works correctly

Comment: Then what is the question?

Comment: You never reset `i` when reading in your strings.  Then again, you never send anything through the socket either.  It looks like you haven't posted all of the relevant code.

Comment: I changed my question, I didn't explain well my issue. My problem is in the recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags) function in my main code of my server. WHat I have to put as int sockfd?

Comment: @ugoren thanks for pointing me to that. I appreciate it. comment stripped (and yeah, it was pretty terrible).

Answer (score 0):

sockfd refers to the socket you are using to communicate with the server. 
http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

Here is the function prototype: ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

If you think about it, you will see that if you don't provide the function with the socket you are using, then how else will it know where to get the data?